# Как обрезать строку с помощью регулярного выражения?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Столкнулась с проблемой связанной с регулярками.
Впервые работаю с ними , и никак не могу добиться того чтобы строка обрезалась после :
(RFA-хххх)

Имеются строки :

```
'Business Ecosystems Console Management System Endpoint Client (RFA-95262)',

'2GIS (RFA-216331)',

'Unified Monitoring and Analysis Platform (KUMA) (RFA-157835)'
```

На выходе должно быть:

```
'Business Ecosystems Console Management System Endpoint Client',

'2GIS',

'Unified Monitoring and Analysis Platform (KUMA)'
```

Любая помощь важна!

Спасибо.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xhRebk/1  попробуйте выражение `\s*\(RFA-\d+\)` возможно это то, что вам нужно

Comment: @ipatev_nn Спасибо вам огромное! Да это выражение отлично работает ! Очень вам балгодарна!